# How to insert a string content into varbinary column in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is a `varbinary` column in database table,in sql statement,we can
use

```
convert(varbinary(10),N'hello') '
```

to  convert string to `varbinary` ,but in rails,how can I do that or there is a another way to
insert a  string content into varbinary column.

Comment: http://www.orthogonalthought.com/blog/index.php/2007/06/mysql-and-ruby-on-rails-datatypes/ check this link as per this link you can declare it as string

Comment: That's strange, your question is an exact copy of this google groups forum post from 2008 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/ab7pLeBnNPU

Comment: This looks relevant:  http://www.dweebd.com/ruby/mysql-varbinary-columns-in-rails-migrations/

Comment: Yeah Its a copy, because I have the same problem.

Comment: If it only contains strings, use varchar (or nvarchar) data type for the column. if not, what's wrong with using the convert?

Comment: @Ugran "Yeah Its a copy, because I have the same problem..." -- hahahaha :D :X

Comment: Guys I had this problem because I was sending SQL server binary data with TinyTds adapter, and I had it wrong by placing binary data into quotes. The actual problem was that I was sending binary data as string :)

Yeah I know it is a silly mistake. Forgive me for wasting your time with bad question...